# react-native-view-pdf to display a pdf in react-native app

Tags: react-native

I am using react-native-view-pdf to display a pdf in my react-native app. reference I used is https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-view-pdf. I used code below =>

```
import PDFView from 'react-native-view-pdf';

const resources = {
  file: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'sample.pdf' : '../assets/sample.pdf',
};
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const resourceType = 'file';

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        {/* Some Controls to change PDF resource */}
        <PDFView
          fadeInDuration={250.0}
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          resource={resources[resourceType]}
          resourceType={resourceType}
          onLoad={() => console.log(`PDF rendered from ${resourceType}`);}
          onError={() => console.log('Cannot render PDF', error)}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

first i faced a syntax error in line of `onLoad={}`
when i removed that line , than i faced error below shown in the below image link.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/shwgL.jpg

i also tried it by manually changing it with README.md which includes following =>

Android

1. Open up `android/app/src/main/java/[...]/MainApplication.java`

   - Add `import com.rumax.reactnative.pdfviewer.PDFViewPackage;` to the imports at the top of the file
   - Add `new PDFViewPackage()` to the list returned by the `getPackages()` method
2. Append the following lines to `android/settings.gradle`:

   ```
   include ':react-native-view-pdf'
   project(':react-native-view-pdf').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-view-pdf/android')
   ```
3. Insert the following lines inside the dependencies block in `android/app/build.gradle`:

   ```
   compile project(':react-native-view-pdf')
   ```

I used first::

> "node_modules/react-native-view-pdf/android/build.gradle" (which is "android/app/build.gradle" in documentation )

I used second:

> "node_modules/react-native-view-pdf/android/src/main/java/com/rumax/reactnative/pdfviewer/PDFView.java" (which is "MainApplication.java" in documentation )

third file was:

> "android/settings.gradle" which i didn't find in "node_modules/react-native-view-pdf/android/"

so i bacame unable to set it manually.

May be I am using wrong file paths to set it manually. If any one have any idea about it or any suggestions for me to solve it in a better way. please help me out.
Or if any other way to solve `"displaying a pdf in react-native"` please provide me that also.

Comment: try changing ` to ' on onload, also check if PDFView was installed correctly, also try linking it via react-native-link react-native-view-pdf

Answer (score 1):

Linking problem is solved after setting it manually and than by using command set RNFB_ANDROID_PERMISSIONS=true in command prompt.

But now still getting an error in using this format with [link] https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-view-pdf
[image: requireNativeComponent "PDFView" was not found in the UIManager.]
anyone having idea about it. or any other way to display a pdf in react-native, kindly let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can try linking manually or recheck if everything is placed correctly

In `android/app/build.gradle`, add/check

```
implementation project(':react-native-view-pdf')
```

In `android/settings.gradle`, add:

```
include ':react-native-view-pdf'
project(':react-native-view-pdf').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-view-pdf/android')
```

In `MainApplication.java` add/check

```
import com.rumax.reactnative.pdfviewer.PDFViewPackage;
```

Then below it:

```
@Override
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
  return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
      new MainReactPackage(),
      new MapsPackage(),
      new PDFViewPackage(), // Check here
      new RCTPdfView(),
      new MapsPackage(),
      new RNFetchBlobPackage()
  );
}
```

Try checking everything and let me know if you missed something on plugin linking

Comment: I am unable to find android/settings.gradle file in the plugin. i have only two things inside android(src folder and build.gradle file)

Comment: It should be there, if not then you have check folder structure.

Comment: i checked it.... i have created my project from expo as `expo init <project name>` that's why i don't have android folder in my project. Isn't there any other way to solve it so that it can work on both ios and android simultaneously.

Comment: You may need to check with Expo plugins I think, https://github.com/xcarpentier/rn-pdf-reader-js, but this is not working properly in iOS you try something like webview for both android and ios

Comment: i used `expo eject` command . that was helpful for me to add react-native folders for android and ios both.

Answer (score 0):

Try "react-native-link react-native-view-pdf".
It will solve the issue.